# I got reshape error but I couldn't find how to fix it

Tags: matlab

I wrote a code and run it. But I had reshape error like below:

> Error using reshape
> Number of elements must not change. Use [] as one of the size inputs to automatically calculate the
> appropriate size for that dimension.

> Error in MT2 (line 37)
> basis_image = reshape(U_theoretical(:, i), [8,8]);"

Could someone help me, please?

```
% Step 1: Generate the random AR-1 sequence
N = 1024;           % Length of the sequence
p = 0.9;            % AR coefficient
mu = 0;             % Mean
sigma = 1;          % Variance

x = zeros(1, N);
for n = 2:N
    x(n) = p * x(n-1) + sqrt(sigma) * randn + mu;
end

% Step 2: Calculate the autocorrelation matrix R
R_theoretical = toeplitz(p.^(0:7));

% Step 3: Calculate the numerical autocorrelation matrix R_num
R_num = zeros(8);
for k = 0:7
    R_num(k+1,:) = sum(x(1:end-k) .* x(1+k:end)) / (N-k);
end

% Step 4: Calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for theoretical R
[U_theoretical, D_theoretical] = eig(R_theoretical);
[~, ind_theoretical] = sort(diag(D_theoretical), 'descend');
U_theoretical = U_theoretical(:, ind_theoretical);
T_theoretical = inv(U_theoretical);

% Step 5: Calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues for numerical R
[U_num, D_num] = eig(R_num);
[~, ind_num] = sort(diag(D_num), 'descend');
U_num = U_num(:, ind_num);
T_num = inv(U_num);

% Step 6: Plot the basis images for theoretical R
figure;
for i = 1:64
    subplot(8, 8, i);
    basis_image = reshape(U_theoretical(:, i), [8,8]);
    imagesc(basis_image);
    colormap(gray);
    title(['Basis ', num2str(i)]);
end

% Step 7: Plot the basis images for numerical R
figure;
for i = 1:64
    subplot(8, 8, i);
    basis_image = reshape(U_num(:, i), [8, 8]);** % ERROR IS IN HERE**
    imagesc(basis_image);
    colormap(gray);
    title(['Basis ', num2str(i)]);
end

% Step 8: Plot the basis images for DCT transform
DCT_matrix = dct(eye(8));
figure;
for i = 1:64
    subplot(8, 8, i);
    basis_image = reshape(DCT_matrix(:, i), [8, 8]);
    imagesc(basis_image);
    colormap(gray);
    title(['DCT Basis ', num2str(i)]);
end
```

I wrote a code and run it. But I had reshape error.

Comment: `U_theoretical` is an 8x8 matrix, so `U_theoretical(:,i)` is an 8x1 vector, which you're trying to `reshape` into an `8x8` matrix. The error is because you can't shape 8 elements into a matrix with 64 elements. It's not clear to me what your expected result is by running `reshape` here

Comment: Please, provide a [mre]. This means to leave out all the code you don’t need to reproduce the error. Most of the code you posted is irrelevant to reproduce the error. All the irrelevant code makes it so much harder to figure out where the error occurs or why it occurs.